# How to check if String has a Letter after a specific letter?

Tags: java, regex, string

Example:

```
String letter = "abc+ab.c+abc.ab";
```

How to check if String letter contains `.` after last `+`?

Comment: Are you looking for `c` immediately after `0` or any time after `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your modified question: to match `.` any time after `+` char try this:

```
Letter.matches(".*\\+.*\\..*");
```

Note: you it was necessary to escape `+` and `.`  with `\\` to match dot and plus literally, since those have a special meaning in regex.

Update: If you only want to match only if there is a dot after last `+` you could do this:

```
Letter.matches(".*\\+.*\\.[^+]*");
```

where the `[^+]` part means any char except `+`.

BTW: I would name your String `letter` instead of `Letter` because of naming conventions

Comment: thnaks brother ...it worked but i have one more issue...

Comment: what if string is like this and `"abc+a.bc+abc.ab"` i want to check if is there any `.` after last `+` thanks @donfuxx

Comment: updated answer. See also a good [tutorial about regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letter.length() - 1; i++) {

   if (letter.charAt(i) == '0' {

       if (letter.charAt(i+1) == 'c' {
          execute desired action here;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean hasLetter(String string, char afterLetter, char letter) {
    int index = string.indexOf(afterLetter);

    if (index == -1 || index == string.length() -1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (string.charAt(index+1) == letter) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Letter.matches(".*0c.*");
```